# jqGrid: Search Toolbar submit automatically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a Toolbar search. How do I make the grid update when someone types in the seach toolbar instead of having to press enter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a searchOnEnter option that you need to set to False.  It would look something like this.

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid('filterToolbar',searchOnEnter:false);
```

See more info on searchOnEnter - **[here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching)**

Comment: I am using v3.8.2 could youe please post an example.

Comment: Correct syntax is `searchOnEnter:false` instead of `searchOnEnter=false`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to be in curly braces:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have autocomplete option on my filterToolbar and dont work when select an option (new value doesn't trigger) how would be the best workaround to this? Also, where should I put the code to trigger a key or something?

Regards